# Getting data to the component with input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

How to getting data from one page to another page but it's show error  i new to angular

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in [{{ mediaItem.id}} in MediaItemComponent

how to get data

first.html

```
<section>
    <media-item [mediaItem]="firstMediaItem"></media-item>
</section>
```

first.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MediaItemComponent} from './secound';

@Component({
    selector: 'media-tracker-app',
    directives: [MediaItemComponent],
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    firstMediaItem = {
        id: 1,
        name: "Firebug",
        medium: "Series",
        category: "Science Fiction",
        year: 2010,
        watchedOn: 1294166565384,
        isFavorite: false
    };
}
```

secound.html

```
<h2>{{ mediaItem.id }}</h2>
<div>Watched on {{ mediaItem.watchedOn }}</div>
<div>{{ mediaItem.category }}</div>
<div>{{ mediaItem.year }}</div>
```

secound.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'media-item',
    templateUrl: 'app/media-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/media-item.component.css']
})
export class MediaItemComponent {
    @Input('mediaItemToWatch') mediaItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOCS says that you should avoid renaming @Input() as you did. That is the cause of problems like this one.

To fix your component behaviour, just change the @Input declaration to this:

secound.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'media-item',
    templateUrl: 'app/media-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/media-item.component.css']
})
export class MediaItemComponent {
    @Input() mediaItem; //HERE, do not rename the input
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first.html

```html
<section>
    <media-item [mediaItemToWatch]="firstMediaItem"></media-item>
</section>
```